# Assessing correlation between paired count data

Tags: r, count-data, paired-data

We are attempting to compare paired animal count data from video and field observations. The video was collected at the same time as the visual field counts. We have three observers:

**ObsA:** Technician A performing visual counts in field
**ObsB:** Technician B performing counts from video
**ObsC:** Technician C performing counts from video

The one wrinkle here is that ObsA and ObsB are the same individual. The video counts occured well after the field counts, but it's possible that some latent knowledge of the field counting influenced the video counting. ObsC has no knowledge/experience with the field counting or animal system -- This is the primary reason there are two video observers.

Counts were performed roughly 30 times over the course of a month. Counts were only performed when animals were present (no 0 data). Generally, our SD values are roughly half the mean for each observer. 
[image: Data Summary statistics]

Our initial assessment of the data shows that there is generally good correlation between our video counts (ObsB and ObsC) and a poorer correlation between the video counts (ObsB and Obs C) and visual observations (ObsA). We'd like to use a statistical test to assess the following:

1. Is there a significant difference in the counts performed by ObsB and ObsC? Here, I would like to assume the null hypothesis is that they are different so that we can say with some confidence that counts made by the two visual observers are comparable.
2. Is there any apparent bias between ObsB and ObsC (in other words, does one ObsC consistently count more animals than ObsB)?
3. What correlation, if any, is there between the video (ObsB and ObsC) and the visual counts? We're primarily interested in correlations between ObsC and ObsA since ObsC has no experience/information about the field visual counts.

I'm looking for help with identifying tests and data transformations to consider using packages/tools available in R. I generally work with continuous data, so I'm little out of my depth with tools for dealing with poisson or negative binomial distributions - or if it even matters here. Thx.

Comment: The bottom right plot seems to have some information cut off. What are the colors?

Comment: Basically, you're after [tag:agreement-statistics].

Comment: Thx. Updated figure.